# CMake external target: reference source dir in custom command

Tags: cmake

in my CMake project, I use an external project called `ep_glslang` which is quite straightforward:

```
ExternalProject_Add(ep_glslang
  DEPENDS ep_vulkan_headers
  URL https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/archive/7.11.3113.tar.gz
  CMAKE_ARGS  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${_PREFIX}
              -DVULKAN_HEADERS_INSTALL_DIR=${_PREFIX}
)
```

Yet, before the configure step I need to run a Python located **at the root of the source directory** of `glslang`.

I created a custom step for my external project:

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(ep_glslang update_glslang_sources
  DEPENDEES update
  DEPENDERS configure
  COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} update_glslang_sources.py
  CMAKE_ARGS  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${_PREFIX}
)
```

It seems to be an idiomatic way of doing that. Yet the step fails for **it does not find the python script**.

How would I **get** the source directory of the external project in order to make things like this:

```
...
COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${EP_SRC_DIR}/update_glslang_sources.py
...
```

I don't find anything, even in the generator expressions, that would help me.

Thank you :)

Comment: For refer to source directory in `ExternalProject_Add` use `<SOURCE_DIR>` expression: `COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} <SOURCE_DIR>/update_glslang_sources.py`.

Comment: Thank you. I post it as an anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by Tsyvarev:

For refer to source directory in `ExternalProject_Add` use `<SOURCE_DIR>` expression: `COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} <SOURCE_DIR>/update_glslang_sources.py`.